# php Header to redirect when post - redirect troubles

Tags: php, post, redirect, header, get

```
header('Location: ../pages/my-files.php?parent_id=' . $_POST['parent_id']);
```

The above needs to redirect the user when a form is submitted, using a hidden variable for `_parent_id`.

However for some reason the user is bieng redirected (or seems to be by looking at the browser URL) to simply `../pages/my-files.php`

Any ideas?

PS. Im certain that `$_POST['parent_id']` has a value.

Comment: Not possible, something else must be wrong.  Based on this code the URL would definitely have at least `?parent_id=` at the end of it.

Comment: My point exactly, I wouldnt normally post such a trivial looking question but I have been looking at it for 20 minutes and there is absolutely nothing wrong. Nicola Peluchetti nailed it though, the rawurlencode worked a charm, I have never used that function before but I shall remember to from now on

Comment: perhaps there was another re-direct occuring in my-files.php when the value passed was invalid..

Comment: Unfortunately not. It was the only redirect bieng called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to encode $_POST['parent_id'] for use in a url?

```
header('Location: ../pages/my-files.php?parent_id=' . rawurlencode($_POST['parent_id']));
```

But it must be something else because your code looks ok. Are you shure that you are redirecting from that point and not from another? Have you tried putting a die() just before that redirection?Most of the times i had your problem i wasn't redirecting from the right place!

Comment: Thanks, never used rawurlencode(); but I shall from now on. That seemed to sort it out.